# Borland C++ 6 with new multi core processors?

Tags: c++builder

I must make some improvements on an application written in Borland C++ 6.

I must purchase new computer for this task. 
I already have known that BCB 6 has some problems with old Athlon 64 processors (freeze when compile).

Howe BCB 6 works with new multi core processors?  (INTEL Core 2 Quad Q6600 with ASUS P5QL PRO )

Are there any problems here?

Comment: No experience with BCB, but in the worst case, consider installing BCB in a single-core VM :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had no problems using C++Builder 6 on a dual-core Pentium 4.

I've also had minimal problems upgrading C++Builder 6 projects to C++Builder 2007, so that might be an option for you too.  (C++Builder 2009 requires that any VCL apps be updated to use Unicode.)

Answer (score 1):

I use BCB 6 on a dual-core Pentium.  The only problem I have is sometimes the compiler pegs CPU usage at 100% (50% per core) for awhile.